# What do I need to know to write code for arm processors, besides the relevant compiler?

Tags: cross-platform

Are there any major differences from PC?

Comment: Besides less memory and storage space? Well, probably not all libraries or system services might be available, or things like physical keyboard and mouse most likely.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done any ARM programming myself though I have run along this fairly extensive piece of online documentation; it is official, from ARM.

ARM Compiler toolchain Developing Software for ARM Processors v4.1

http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0471c/index.html

A brief rundown of what is included:

- Description of key features of ARM Architecture Versions
- Notes on Embedded Software Development
- Documentation of the ARM C Library
- Mixing of C, C++ and Assembly
- Debugging
- Semihosting
- Useful command line options
- Etc